# windows redis-client connect to docker server failed

Tags: windows, docker, redis

I am using windows10, redis-64bit, I started a redis container with command:

```
docker run --name myredis -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

when I try to connect to this container using:

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.99.1 -p 6379
```

it shows:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 192.168.99.1:6379: Unknown error
```

here, `192.168.99.1` is my virtual machine ip address, anyone know how to solve this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a redis container from a remote server you should do the following:

- Start redis container on host (192.168.99.1):

  ```
  docker run --name myredis -p 7000:6379 -d redis redis-server
  ```
- Connect via remote server:

  ```
  redis-cli -h 192.168.99.1 -p 7000
  ```

Comment: thanks for your anwser, still the same error, this working on your machine?

Comment: Yes. did you map the port? and check if port 7000 is open through firewall

Comment: thanks for your help, can you help me also with, how to restart the container after the redis-server is down? I have tried: `docker container start myredis redis-server` but failed

Comment: `docker start myredis` . If you find my answer helpful please accept it. Thanks.